# duplicate printers windows 2012 r2 (same printer)

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, remote, printer

We have the following setup:

Windows 2012r2 Remote desktop server (x1)
Windows 2012r2 Print server

Network printers are added once to the print server
Printers are installed to users remote desktop session by them navigating to \print_server and right clicking to connect to a printer.

Sometimes (and it seems to be only affecting one printer) we are getting print failures.

When I investigate the user, I can see that the same printer appears to have multiple versions of itself listed, but not duplicated in the control panel.

See screenshot. (domain name blanked out)

[Duplicate printer display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wIeXj.png)

I cannot see duplicate printers in the print server, its only listed once, and it only seems to happen to one or two users.

I don't have any group policies in place to push printers, or logon scripts.

Its a fairly simple setup as we only have approx 30 staff and only about 10 of them use our network etc.

Some additional information:

- We only allow a user one session, they always reconnect to it
- print redirection is off on the connections (so not a local instance of the printer)
- We get the issue that the printer will not print until deleted, and re-added - gives various errors, even though it shows as connected / on etc.

Comment: I wonder if they are just from remote sessions that have not been logged off

Comment: @Drifter104, how would this be? Its only showing on one or two users. They are not re-directed printers.?

Comment: Maybe they are just bad a logging off. Simple answer be to look to see if they have multiple sessions open

Comment: We have rds set to reconnect to the same session and only 1 session per user?

Comment: That's the type of information that belongs in the question

Comment: I found this: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/71d06204-3735-4473-8bc9-20be9e19090e/ The problem seems to have something do to with client side print rendering. The fix recommended was to delete the print server out of the "Servers" key in this registry key: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Print\Providers\Client Side Rendering Print Provider\Servers

Comment: Then restart the spooler service, which greys out all the offending printers in "Devices and Printers". After that its just a matter of deleting the greyed out printers from your "Devices and Printers" control panel. Note: I have not tested this.  I am only relaying information gleaned from a discussion.

Comment: @Art.Vandelay05 , thanks, I too saw that , but was hesitant to start hacking around in the registry as it was not quite the same issue as I have had - I may give it a go after the christmas rush if I don't find another solution. Thanks

Comment: You're welcome.  I understand your hesitation to hacking around in the registry since the situation isn't exactly the same as yours.

Comment: Your screenshot has everything blacked out so there's no way for us to know what's what. Are the other printer "instances" being redirected via RDS to the user sessions?

Comment: @joeqwerty -> I just blanked out the domain name, the other printers are fine. Its just the **KH Despatch** printer, which, when you select properties, shows exactly the same text, multiple time.